# How to design a font like this?

Tags: fonts, font-design

I saw a lot of font designs like this, but haven't found any tutorials on how to create such a font. How can I create a font like this?

[image: Like the font in this picture]

Comment: This is not a font. (Most likely.)

Comment: Hello Echo, welcome to GD.SE. As-is, your question is very broad. Could you show us what you have tried, where you are stuck, and why the result doesn't fulfill your needs? You can always [edit] your question to add new info. Thanks! If you have any questions about GDSE, have a look at the help or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is specifically for Adobe Illustrator, but the principle will apply to any package...

First, you need to draw the letter shapes with lines. It will probably help to work on a grid for this step. (I have shown the 'exploded' view just so that you can see the individual lines, that's not a step in the process.)
[image]

Next, increase the thickness of the lines to something that you like the look of and change the 'End Caps' to rounded (middle button, top row, directly underneath the line weight.
[image]
Finally, choose your colours and then set the blending mode of the lines to 'darken' or 'multiply' (or experiment with other blending modes).
[image]
Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris! I thought maybe there would be some skills before.(Actually it is.) I am not good at using the pen tool. >.< Can you also tell me how to draw a perfect "C" like you? Thanks again.

Comment: In Illustrator, draw a circle, then go to Object > Path > Add Anchor Points. This will add points in between the default four points to give you eight in total. You can then delete the points that you don't need to leave a portion of a perfect circle. Then you just need to scale it to look nice. You can repeatedly use Add Anchor Points if you need more points to play with. It works on any path, but I find it most useful on circles and curves.

Comment: Still difficult for me, but much better! Thanks, Chris~☺️

Answer (score 2):

Ok so in order to design this you might want to have the font used in that design but I will show you how to create the overlapping effect you see in that image. You might want to draw this over the text where you want to use this.

So design tall rectangles and the select them with your white arrow (a) and a small dot will appear next to each corner of the objects box.

[image: 1]]

Simply using the same white arrow tool drag one of these dots so you can see the corners become totally round.

[image: 2]]

Do this to all your rectangles. Then select them and make tem overlap

[image: 3]]

After this choose your Transparency menu on the side bar or add it by going to top menu "Window > Transparency".
From the drop down menu choose Multiply.

[image: 4]]

Then to enhance the effect you can change the objects' opacity also.

[image: 5]]

Note that some colours will work better than others.

Hope this was useful to you.